# Collapsible Sidebar working on Bootstrap 3.0.3 but not 3.3.7

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to implement what's shown on https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/navigation-sidebar-with-toggle in Bootstrap 3.3.7

The above was written in Bootstrap 3.0.3. When I use 3.0.3 on my local machine, it works exactly as rendered on the above link. However, when I swap to 3.3.7 (which is being used on the project where I want this menu) it doesn't.

I'm trying to work out what's different between 3.0.3 and 3.3.7 which would cause this. The only class I can see in the CSS which comes with Bootstrap is `.row`:

```
.row {
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-right:0px;
}
```

When I comment this out, it makes no difference anyway. The other declarations in the CSS seem to be non-Bootstrap, so not sure why changing version would do this.

I've gone through portions of the CSS and tried to comment things out or change values but I can't figure this out. Specifically anything involving `(-)150px` and `70px` since this seems to be controlling widths and position.

The way it renders is like this (menu open):

[image]

And then this when the menu is closed - disappears outside the left edge of the browser.

[image]

I want to implement a collapsible left sidebar where the button to toggle it is visible, like on the above link. I can't find any tutorials for Bootstrap 3.3.7 which do this - even though it seems a very common feature on many websites.

Please can someone help me to get this working, or advise an alternative that is compatible with 3.3.7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will be helpful.
I have updated the jQuery to jquery-3.3.1.min.js and in order to display the icons correctly, I have changed the padding-right from 65px to 30px.

```js
$("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("active");
});
```

```css
.row {
 margin-left: 0px;
 margin-right: 0px;
}
#wrapper {
 padding-left: 70px;
 transition: all .4s ease 0s;
 height: 100%
}
#sidebar-wrapper {
 margin-left: -150px;
 left: 70px;
 width: 150px;
 background: #222;
 position: fixed;
 height: 100%;
 z-index: 10000;
 transition: all .4s ease 0s;
}
.sidebar-nav {
 display: block;
 float: left;
 width: 150px;
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
#page-content-wrapper {
 padding-left: 0;
 margin-left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}
#wrapper.active {
 padding-left: 150px;
}
#wrapper.active #sidebar-wrapper {
 left: 150px;
}
#page-content-wrapper {
 width: 100%;
}
#sidebar_menu li a, .sidebar-nav li a {
 color: #999;
 display: block;
 float: left;
 text-decoration: none;
 width: 150px;
 background: #252525;
 border-top: 1px solid #373737;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #1A1A1A;
 -webkit-transition: background .5s;
 -moz-transition: background .5s;
 -o-transition: background .5s;
 -ms-transition: background .5s;
 transition: background .5s;
}
.sidebar_name {
 padding-top: 25px;
 color: #fff;
 opacity: .7;
}
.sidebar-nav li {
 line-height: 40px;
 text-indent: 20px;
}
.sidebar-nav li a {
 color: #999999;
 display: block;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
 color: #fff;
 background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
 text-decoration: none;
}
.sidebar-nav li a:active, .sidebar-nav li a:focus {
 text-decoration: none;
}
.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
 height: 65px;
 line-height: 60px;
 font-size: 18px;
}
.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a {
 color: #999999;
}
.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a:hover {
 color: #fff;
 background: none;
}
#main_icon {
 float: right;
 padding-right: 30px;
 padding-top: 20px;
}
.sub_icon {
 float: right;
 padding-right: 30px;
 padding-top: 10px;
}
.content-header {
 height: 65px;
 line-height: 65px;
}
.content-header h1 {
 margin: 0;
 margin-left: 20px;
 line-height: 65px;
 display: inline-block;
}

@media (max-width:767px) {
#wrapper {
 padding-left: 70px;
 transition: all .4s ease 0s;
}
#sidebar-wrapper {
 left: 70px;
}
#wrapper.active {
 padding-left: 150px;
}
#wrapper.active #sidebar-wrapper {
 left: 150px;
 width: 150px;
 transition: all .4s ease 0s;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<body>
<div id="wrapper" class="active"> 
  
  <!-- Sidebar --> 
  <!-- Sidebar -->
  <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
    <ul id="sidebar_menu" class="sidebar-nav">
      <li class="sidebar-brand"><a id="menu-toggle" href="#">Menu<span id="main_icon" class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></span></a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="sidebar-nav" id="sidebar">
      <li><a>Link1<span class="sub_icon glyphicon glyphicon-link"></span></a></li>
      <li><a>link2<span class="sub_icon glyphicon glyphicon-link"></span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
  <!-- Page content -->
  <div id="page-content-wrapper"> 
    <!-- Keep all page content within the page-content inset div! -->
    <div class="page-content inset">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <p class="well lead">An Experiment using the sidebar template from startbootstrap.com which I integrated in my website (<a href="http://animeshmanglik.name">animeshmanglik.name</a>)</p>
          <p class="well lead">Click on the Menu to Toggle Sidebar . Hope you enjoy it!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```